# Reducing product to a maximum total size

Tags: math

If I have a product:

```
float d = ( a * b * c );
```

And it exceeds some maximum size (e, in my example), how can I reduce the terms a, b and c to make it fit?

```
if ( d > e )
{
    // reduce a, b and c by some fixed percentage, such that ( a * b * c ) == e
}
```

It's probably really simple, but I can't figure it out!

Comment: you want to reduce them by an equal percentage? so that the ratio of `a` to `b` to `c` stays the same?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scale them each by the cube root of the overall ratio.

```
fac = exp(log(e/d)/3)
a *= fac
b *= fac
c *= fac
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <math.h>
…
double scale = cbrt(e / d);
float new_a = a * scale;
float new_b = b * scale;
float new_c = c * scale;
```

Note that `new_a * new_b * new_c` as computed above may not be exactly `e`. It may be slightly above. If you want the product to absolutely be below `e`, take a safety ratio like `scale = cbrt(0.5 * e / d);`